# Webstart application doesn´t get updated via desktop-shortcut

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start, shortcut-file

Our webstart-application doesn't update correctly via desktop-shortcut when settings the option "`<shortcut online="[true|false]">`" to false. It seems to work fine when setting it to true but I didn't realy understand the meaning of that flag. JNLP-Spec says:

**"Can be used to describe the application's preference for creating a shortcut to run online or offline."**

What does that mean in concrete? Is it the same as the "offline_allowed" flag or what exactly is the difference?

Comment: What is the option? You mentioned it as "".

Comment: sorry, updated the question :)